# Открыть документ xls в окне приложения Excel

Tags: python

Мне нужно что бы по нажатию на кнопку моего приложения открылся мой документ ексель. Помогите реализовать функцыю, результатом которой будет запущено окно программы Excel с открытым моим документом.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть вариант, что программа эксель не установлена, так же есть вариант, что программа эксель не может быть установлена (к примеру убунту)
Но в сущности это является вызовом системной команды, то есть открыть приложение, с файлом...

```
import os
os.system(f'path_to_programm {file}')
```

здесь file это переменная содержащая путь к файлу, path_to_programm путь к исполняемому файлу программы эксель.
то есть программа и файл могут быть любыми к примеру открытие текстового файла блокнотом.
наличие программы проверяется наличием исполняемого файла

Comment: Спасибо, это сработало так как нужно!